# angular compilation error Expected arguments in components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error on my angular component when i create a variable with

```
let myVar = new MyModel();
```

I have a compilation error Expected 5 arguments but got 0.
I have a form and i want to set each property of my Object myVar in the submit function.
MyModel

```
export class MyModel{
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public text1: string, 
        public text2:string,
        public text3: number, 
        public text4: string) { }
}

onSubmit() {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
      const formValue = this.myForm.value;
      this.myVar .text1= formValue['text1'];
      this.myVar .text2= formValue['text2'];
      this.myVar .text3= formValue['text3'];
      this.myVar .text4 = formValue['text4'];
}
```

Have you an idea to avoid this compilation error.
I want to get value enterred by user in my form

Answer (score 0):

You've added all your arguments in the constructor, so you must pass them to create an instance of MyModel.

If you want to set them one by one like in your example, you can have your class like this:

```
export class MyModel {
  public id: number;
  public text1: string;
  public text2: string;
  public text3: number;
  public text4: string;
}

let myVar = new MyModel();
```